# DHTMLX dhtmlxForm.send() Throws HTTP Status 400 - "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Tags: javascript, apache, http-headers, dhtmlx, http-status-code-400

This all started when we moved to DHTMLX v4.0.3.  The dhtmlxForm.send() function now throws HTTP Status 400 - "*The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.*"  I don't see anything wrong with the POST.  I did notice they are now including a randomly generated item "dhxr1422484613542" that does not have a value.  Any idea why this is now throwing a HTTP 400?  Thanks!

**The Headers Tab:**
[image]
**The Preview Tab:**
[image]
**The JavaScript:**

```
dhtmlxEvent(window,"load",function(){
    var dhxLayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, '1C');

    var f = dhxLayout.cells("a").attachForm([
        {type:"settings", position:"label-left", labelAlign:"right", labelWidth:150, inputWidth:150},
        {type:"hidden", name:"method", value:"getJson"},
        {type:"hidden", name:"proc", value:"c3.chgpwd"},
        {type:"password", name:"oldpwd", label:"Current Password", required:true},
        {type:"password", id:"newpwd", name:"newpwd", label:"New Password", required:true},
        {type:"password", name:"confirmpwd", label:"New Password (Again)", required:true},
        {type:"button", name:"submit", width:50, offsetLeft:150, value:"Submit"}
    ]);
    f.attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(name){
        /* Here is the POST that used to work, but since v4.0.3 it throws a HTTP 400 */
        f.send("lib.cfc?method=getJson&proc=c3.chgpwd","post",function(loader, response){
            console.log(response);  /*This is never reached, see attachments for the error reported during the POST*/
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that apache cannot handle url parameters when the equal symbol is missing after the name.

So a url such as:

```
 http://domain.com?x=22&y
```

is not understandable by apache.

I guess the dhtmlx team does not use apache.

Comment: But I'm doing a POST. Not a GET. I updated to DHTMLX 4.1.2 and the issue went away.

Comment: Apache is expecting name=value in both GET and POST.  In 4.1.2, you're probably turning off cache with `window.dhx4.ajax.cache = false;`